# How to save and retrieve boolean values instead of string when using jsonb columns in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

When I check out specific values and submit the form, it updates the values: true/false. But when I open the edit form, the checkboxes are not checked out.

I'm using storext gem

migration

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :title
...
      t.jsonb :features, null: false, default: {}
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

model

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  include Storext.model

  store_attributes :features do
    tv Boolean, default: false
    wifi Boolean, default: false
  end
```

_form

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.fields_for :features do |ff| %>
      <% property.features.each do |feature, status| %>
        <%= ff.label feature do %>
          <%= ff.check_box feature, {checked: status}, true, false %>
          <%= feature %> (<%= status %>)
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Not sure how to fix this but I know what the problem is about. The default value of attributes is **false(falseClass)** but when I submit the form with some checkbox checked out it's **String** like "true"

And when I set a status of a checkbox `{checked: status}` it renders as `{checked: "true"}` instead of `{checked: true}` This is why it't not marked as checked.

**UPDATE 2**

Doing something like this kind of works

```
serialize :features, HashSerializer

class HashSerializer
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash.transform_values { |val| ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(val) }
  end

  def self.load(hash)
    (hash || {}).with_indifferent_access
  end
end
```

Comment: I _think_ you can pass `checked: true` or false in the options hash

Comment: Yes, but I can't do something like `{checked: status}` And adding logic like ```<% if status %>``` - render it with `checked: true` doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: @kirqe Well, ask from JavaScript. JavaScript knows it how todo easily :)

Comment: You can convert 'true' and 'false' to booleans by using a conditional:
status == 'true'